# Evaluating what column variable name is missing in one data table compared to other data table and automatically adding columns missing

Tags: r

Let's say that I have a two data tables:

First data table has five columns with following names: 'date', 'pitch_type', 'start_speed', 'tfs', and 'batter_name'

Second data table has three columns with following names: 'date', 'pitch_type', and 'start_speed' (e.g. missing 'tfs' and 'batter_name, compared to first table)

I actually have 1000 data tables and there are few data tables out of 1000 that has inconsistent column numbers. (e.g. In some data tables, some columns are missing)

I want to use code like this to add a missing columns so that all data table has 5 columns: (This is because I want to rbind all 1000 data tables)

```
if(!("pitcher_name" %in% colnames(second_datatable))){

    second_datatable$pitcher_name <- NA
    master_data_table <- rbind(master_data_table,second_datatable)

  }
```

Some tables miss different columns and it is cumbersome to write a script above for all five columns and it will slow the speed down. Is there a way to automatically have code recognize which of five column types missing and add it?

Comment: Did you try the `merge()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rbind.fill()` in the `plyr` library to do this automatically.

```
library('plyr')
master_data_table = rbind.fill(master_data_table, second_data_table)
```

If any of the dataframes are missing columns, it will automatically add them and fill them in with `NA`.

Comment: That was extremely helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `rbindlist` from `data.table` after placing the datasets in a `list`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.4+
rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill=TRUE)
```

Suppose the object names are all starting with 'df' followed by numbers, we can get all the datasets in a list by using `mget` to get the value stored in the vector of character string objects from the `ls` output.

```
lst <- mget(ls(pattern=^df\\d+')) 
rbindlist(lst, fill=TRUE)
```

We may not need to create any objects in the global environment.  All the files can be read directly in a list using either `fread` from `data.table` or `read.csv/read.table` from `base R` and then `rbind` all the datasets using `rbindlist`.

```
files <- list.files()#all files in the working directory
rbindlist(lapply(files, fread), fill=TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1=1:5, v2=6:10)
df2 <- data.frame(v2=11:15, v3=16:20)
```